# What's the difference between fgets and current?

Tags: php

In the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php), the `SplFileObject` has two methods that seem very similar:

`$file->fgets()`

> Gets a line from the file.

`$file->current()`

> Retrieves the current line of the file.

The documentation on procedural `fgets` is even closer to `current()`:

> Gets line from file pointer.

But there's no note about one being an alias of the other. Both take no parameters. What is the difference between these?

Comment: If you downvote, please let me know why so I can improve the question. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why people downvote it, but I'd also like to know the fundamental difference between these methods. They look ambiguous and the difference is tiny.

Comment: Seems like the only difference is the READ_CSV thing for current, but you probably saw that too. It's a good question.

Comment: It's a good question indeed

Comment: @rjdown - that's what I suspect. In which case it's an alias for `fgets` unless `read_csv` is set, in which case it's `fgetcsv`. I was wondering if there was any other difference (seems kind of pointless, it's more code to do the same thing...). If there's no answer by tomorrow I'll dig into the source and see what I can C. Oh look! Thanks Axalix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real difference that matter is, e.g. we have this file

```
foo
bar
```

The below function will print `foo bar`

```
$file = new \SplFileObject("test.txt");
while (!$file->eof()) {
    echo $file->fgets();
}
```

But this function will print `foo` continuously

```
$file = new \SplFileObject("test.txt");
while (!$file->eof()) {
    echo $file->current();
}
```

Because `fgets` starts from begin and reading the next line which is the first line, then it reads the next line which is the seconds line and stops because it found end of file but `current` always read the current line and never goes to next line so it never breaks of the loop, you need to use `next` function to read next line, so the first code is equivalent with:

```
$file = new \SplFileObject("test.txt");
while (!$file->eof()) {
    echo $file->current();
    $file->next();
}
```

**Edit:** also check [Josiah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30290010/3546760) answer about the difference with flag and [Axalix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30290219/3546760) to see the source code diffrence

Comment: So `current` doesn't move the pointer? Interesting. What would this be useful for?

Comment: Well maybe because you want to read the line and check its value before to continue to the next line

Comment: I think @Almis is right. Look at the comments above the methods in the src. code. `Return current line from file` and `Rturn next line from file`

Comment: Ok, I had to try it. That's a lot of `foo`. Thanks! Add the bit about the CSV flag and I think this will be the most complete answer.

Comment: you already explained that part so instead of repeating what you wrote I just linked your answers

Comment: Now I wish we could make PHP documentation little bit better about these things :)

Comment: Go add user notes! Thanks for your help guys. We made the internet a better place.

Answer (score 2):

One difference is that `current` can function as `fgetcsv` or `fgets` [depending on whether the  `SplFileObject::READ_CSV` flag is set](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.current.php#refsect1-splfileobject.current-returnvalues). The underlying implementation is almost the same (without moving the pointer, see other answers) as either, depending on that flag.

This means that `current` can either return a string or an array, depending on the presence of the flag.

Presumably this is done for code portability, though it seems like it would be more code than `fgetcsv` to accomplish the same work, and perhaps minutely less performant due to the extra logical call (see Axalix's answer).

Answer (score 1):

There are some differences in implementation. It seems like `fgets` is shorter and it only does what is says *Reads the line from a file*

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/4d9a1883aa764e502990488d2e8b9c978be6fbd2/ext/spl/spl_directory.c

```
/* {{{ proto string SplFileObject::current()
   Return current line from file */
SPL_METHOD(SplFileObject, current)
{
    spl_filesystem_object *intern = Z_SPLFILESYSTEM_P(getThis());

    if (zend_parse_parameters_none() == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    if(!intern->u.file.stream) {
        zend_throw_exception_ex(spl_ce_RuntimeException, 0, "Object not initialized");
        return;
    }

    if (!intern->u.file.current_line && Z_ISUNDEF(intern->u.file.current_zval)) {
        spl_filesystem_file_read_line(getThis(), intern, 1);
    }
    if (intern->u.file.current_line && (!SPL_HAS_FLAG(intern->flags, SPL_FILE_OBJECT_READ_CSV) || Z_ISUNDEF(intern->u.file.current_zval))) {
        RETURN_STRINGL(intern->u.file.current_line, intern->u.file.current_line_len);
    } else if (!Z_ISUNDEF(intern->u.file.current_zval)) {
        RETURN_ZVAL(&intern->u.file.current_zval, 1, 0);
    }
    RETURN_FALSE;
} /* }}} */
```

VS

```
/* {{{ proto string SplFileObject::fgets()
   Rturn next line from file */
SPL_METHOD(SplFileObject, fgets)
{
    spl_filesystem_object *intern = Z_SPLFILESYSTEM_P(getThis());

    if (zend_parse_parameters_none() == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    if(!intern->u.file.stream) {
        zend_throw_exception_ex(spl_ce_RuntimeException, 0, "Object not initialized");
        return;
    }

    if (spl_filesystem_file_read(intern, 0) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    RETURN_STRINGL(intern->u.file.current_line, intern->u.file.current_line_len);
} /* }}} */
```

---

**Edit:**
 So the difference is in return. `current` (if some flags are set) may return RETURN_ZVAL (php array for this case) OR string OR. `fgets` returns strings or FALSE.  Also `if (spl_filesystem_file_read(intern, 0) == FAILURE) {` which is way faster than anything else if we just want to read a line from a file w/o making any other work.

Comment: I see `RETURN_STRINGL(intern->u.file.current_line, intern->u.file.current_line_len);` in both. What does `if (!intern->u.file.current_line && Z_ISUNDEF(intern->u.file.current_zval)) {
        spl_filesystem_file_read_line(getThis(), intern, 1);
    }` do?

Comment: Thanks. I think that edit answers my question. I'll wait around a few minutes and see if any more info comes to light. Can you think of a case where you would choose `current()` over one of the others? It seems somewhat pointless.